# Flipping $n$ sticky coins until they are all heads

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, asymptotics, markov-chains

Consider a collection of $n$ coins, of which $k$ initially are heads. These coins are "sticky" and, when flipped, remain the same with probability $p > 1/2$, and flip over with probability $1-p < 1/2$. Time proceeds in synchronous rounds, and in each round, we flip each coin. As a function of $k$, $p$, and $n$, what is the expected number of rounds before all coins land heads?

In particular, I am interested in a lower bound on the expected number of rounds before all coins land heads (especially for $k=n-1$). For a constant $p$, the expected number of rounds before all coins land heads is lower-bounded by an exponential function, but for $p \approx 1 - \frac{1}{poly(n)}$, the answer is less clear.

It's also possible to frame this question as a Markov chain (which can also be thought of as a Kronecker product of $n$ smaller two-state Markov chains). In this formulation, it is easy to write a formula for the expected number of rounds before all coins land heads, but I'm interested in a clean asymptotic expression in $k$, $n$, and $p$.

Edit: In the Markov chain formulation, the transition matrix is a $2^n$ by $2^n$ matrix $P$ where the $(i,j)^{th}$ entry is the probability of transitioning from state $i$ to $j$. We can assume that the all-heads state is an absorbing state and therefore write $P$ as \begin{pmatrix} Q&R \\ \mathbf{0} &1\end{pmatrix} where $Q$ is a $2^n - 1$ by $2^n - 1$ matrix, $R$ is a $2^n - 1$ by $1$ matrix, and $\mathbf{0}$ is a $1$ by $2^n - 1$ matrix of all zeroes. Now, letting $N = (I - Q)^{-1}$ (or equivalently $N = \sum_{k=1}^\infty Q^k$) be the fundamental matrix, we can see that the expected number of steps until absorption from a state $i$ is the $i^{th}$ entry of $N \mathbf{1}$. (Wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain#Expected_number_of_steps).)
However, this expression still seems nontrivial to analyze with respect to asymptotic bounds.

Comment: "In this formulation, it is easy to write a formula for the expected number of rounds" 
So you have the answer for the main question in the first paragraph, right ? You don't think that it would be useful to include it?

Comment: Thanks for the comment -- I just added it!

Comment: It might be easier (or maybe not) to work with an $n+1$ by $n+1$ matrix where state $i$ represents $i$ heads (starting with state $0$). Maybe that’s what you meant by a Kronecker product of smaller Markov chains - I’m not familiar with that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! We also tried that -- the transition probabilities quickly get quite unwieldy, and we weren't sure how to analyze them. The Kronecker product results in the larger $2^n$ by $2^n$ matrix.

Comment: I don't think that $n+1$ states are enough, if we flip the coins sequentially (that's the idea, no?) It would be enough only if we flip the coins randomly - but that's a different problem.

Comment: @leonbloy "in each round, we flip each coin". I think that means that every coin is flipped every round.

Comment: @DavidLukeThiessen I had assumed that the game stopped whenever all coins land heads.... (no necessarily after a full circle). My bad, I guess.

Comment: @leonbloy It's worth clarifying whether the flips happen simultaneously or sequentially and whether the game would stop part-way through a round. I had considered the coins being flipped simultaneously because it's simpler, but you actually make a good point.

Comment: Good question! In our formulation, the flips happen simultaneously, and the game doesn't stop partway through a round.